# German mobile phone numbers for ING-DiBa internet banking log-in

Tags: bank-account, germany

I have opened a girokonto with ING-DiBa when I was living in Germany. I have left Germany but I am still using the girokonto.

Some time in 2023, they asked me to enter a German mobile phone number for receiving one-time passwords, but I don't have a German phone number, so I just have skipped it.

Now when I try to log in from my PC it mandates me to enter a German phone number and does not allow me to skip that step. Is there any way to get around this? I can send transfers etc using the ING-DiBa mobile app, but sometimes working with the PC version internet banking is more convenient. Apparently, I do not want to create a new phone number (which is not easy while not living in Germany).

Comment: The app does allow login via barcode. Have you tried this? You just need the app.

Comment: Have tried that too. It shows the same page asking to enter a German mobile phone number.

Comment: Did you try to contact their support and ask if it is possible that they simply set another non-German phone number (that you have) for your account? I have German bank accounts where a German phone number was required when opening the accounts, but I was able to set a non-German phone number after opening them - either by myself when logged in to mobile/online banking or after asking their support. So I was able to skip the requirement of using some +49 number this way.

Comment: Following your comment, I have emailed their customer service. They responded that "We have noted that from now on we will no longer send you one-time passwords by SMS, but by post." Now I can log-in from my PC while not having to enter a German phone number. It seems the customer service has done something for my personal data in their system. So problem solved! Many thanks!